# Como habilitar y desabilitar un boton en React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hola a todos soy nueva en esto y estoy aprendiendo React js, en este caso quiero que mi botón cambiar Status este deshabilitado cuando el trabajador este Activo, he intentado hacerlo pero no lo he podido lograr, espero y me puedan explicar

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function Datos() {

  const [btnActivo, SetBtnActivo]= useState (false);

  const [usuarios, setUsuarios]= useState([
      {id: 1, nombre: "Arturo Borja", puesto:"programador Backend", status: "Activo"},
      {id: 2, nombre: "Armando Rojas", puesto:"Contador", status: "Vacaciones"},
      {id: 3, nombre: "Epifania Salinas", puesto:"Abogado", status: "Activo"},
      {id: 4, nombre: "Sebastian Cruz", puesto:"Dentista", status: "Pendiente"},
      {id: 5, nombre: "Luis Peralta", puesto:"Oftamologo", status: "Vacaciones"},
      {id: 6, nombre: "Sergio Torres", puesto:"Contador", status: "Activo"},
      {id: 7, nombre: "Amalia Días", puesto:"Dentista", status: "Pendiente"},
      {id: 8, nombre: "María Flores", puesto:"programador Frontend", status: "Activo"},
      {id: 9, nombre: "Anna Torres", puesto:"Programador Fullstack", status: "Vacaciones"},
      {id: 10, nombre: "Lizbeth Corrales", puesto:"Abogado", status: "Pendiente"},
  ])

  return (
      <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">
          <div className="App">
              <br/>
              <h4>Lista de Empleados</h4><br/><br/><br/>
              <table className="table">
              <thead class="thead-dark">
                  <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>PUESTO</th>
                  <th>STATUS</th>
                  <th></th>
                  <th></th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  {usuarios.map(usuarios=>(
                  <tr>
                      <td>{usuarios.id}</td>
                      <td>{usuarios.nombre}</td>
                      <td>{usuarios.puesto}</td>
                      <td>{usuarios.status}</td>
                      <td><a href='/Detalles'><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Información</button></a></td>
                      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Cambiar Status</button></td>
                  </tr>
                  ))}
              </tbody>
              </table> 
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      
  );
}
export default Datos;
```

[image: Resultado]

Answer (score 2):

Lo que deberías hacer es comprobar si el estado es "activo" y en ese caso añadirle el atributo "disabled", con el condicional.

Una manera sencilla seria la siguiente:

```
<td><button type="button" disabled = {usuarios.status === "Activo"}  class="btn btn-success">Cambiar Status</button></td>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya he implementado el cambio